# How to catch an exception that occurred on a spark worker?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
val HTF = new HashingTF(50000)
val Tf = Case.map(row=>
    HTF.transform(row)
).cache()
val Idf = new IDF().fit(Tf)

try
{
  Idf.transform(Tf).map(x=>LabeledPoint(1,x))
}
catch {
  case ex:Throwable=>
    println(ex.getMessage)
}
```

Code like this isn't working.

HashingTF/Idf belongs to org.spark.mllib.feature.

I'm still getting an exception that says

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to get broadcast_5_piece0 of broadcast_5
```

I cannot see any of my files in the error log, how do I debug this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the worker ran out of memory.

**Instant temporary Fix:**

Run the application without caching.

Just remove `.cache()`

**How to Debug:**

Probably Spark UI might have the complete exception details.

- check Stage details
- check the logs and thread dump in Executor tab

If you find multiple exceptions or errors try to resolve it in sequence.

Most of the times resolving 1st error will resolve subsequent errors.